# OpenWrt slow internet

Tags: openwrt

I have a router from my ISP which is connected with an TP-Link WR1043ND with OpenWrt installed.

I pay for a 100MBit connection and if I try a speedtest, I get 80-95 Mbit, but only if I connect my ISP router directly with my PC. If I connect with ISP router by wifi (through a thick wall), I get ~30Mbits, which is ok. But if I connect my PC (with CAT6 cable) with the OpenWrt Router, I only get 8-9 MBit. Is there a way to find out, why I lose 80% of speed on OpenWRT router?

Here are some speedtest results:

- Cable connection to ISP router: http://www.dslreports.com/speedtest/15949958
- WireLess over ISP Router wifi: http://www.dslreports.com/speedtest/15949861
- Cable connection through OpenWRT router: http://www.dslreports.com/speedtest/15949758

I already tried the following:

- Switch cables to check if the cable is the problem
- OpenWrt reset
- OpenWrt update to latest version

Comment: I wonder if your `ISP is cheating speed test`. Try to google that.

Comment: What's your [bufferbloat](http://www.dslreports.com/speedtest?nav=2)

Comment: Not sure if ISP is cheating, but I can see big speed difference not only on speedtest, but also on file downloads, so there must be another problem
@Ramhound: Just added dslreport links to question

Comment: Your results don't show your bufferbloat

Comment: It shows bufferfloats of grad c (<200) for the fast ISP connection and grad B (Less than 60ms) for the openwrt connection. So I am not sure, but i think, that will not help me finding a solution :/